# Java - Integer to 4 character Hex

Tags: java, hex

How Can I convert an integer into a 4 character hex number.  I need the extra padding of 0s if it isnt long enough.

So 2 -> 0x0002, 18 -> 0x0012 etc

I am using Java

Comment: @Juvanis It's easy to do this with String.format() but you have to know about it. It's not totally obvious. I think this is a fair question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `String.format("%04X", decInt);`?

If you want to add `0x` part just place it at start of pattern used in this method like `String.format("0x%04X", decInt);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String toPaddedHex(int i) {
    return String.format("0x%04X", i);
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(toPaddedHex(123));
```

Prints:

```
0x007B
```